# Creating a function with a parametric return type

Tags: julia

I have a situation where I'd like to set a function with a parametric return type - a simplified example below. It seems like this is not currently possible - what is the logical idiom to use instead? It is not obvious to me how to achieve reasonable code re-use.

```
struct Output{T <: Number}
    other_details::String # lots of stuff here
    numeric_output::T
end

function get_output{T <: Number}(input)::Output{T}
    transformed_input = input
    # Do stuff to transformed_input
    Output{T}(
        "lots of data",
        transformed_input
    )
end

input = 1::Int64
get_output{Float64}(input)
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you might have noticed, parametrically defined functions, e.g. functions like `foo{T}(x)`, can only be defined if they are constructors for a type (which has already been defined). What you can do instead is take the desired output type as a function argument, like this:

```
struct Output{T <: Number}
    other_details::String
    numeric_output::T
end

function get_output(::Type{T}, input) where {T <: Number}
    Output("lots of data", T(input))
end
```

```
julia> get_output(Float64, 1)
Output{Float64}("lots of data", 1.0)
```

Note that a literal `1` is already an integer. There's no need to write `1::Int64`.

Also note the use of a [singleton type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-singleton-types) in the function signature. This only serves to restrict the dispatch. You could write `get_output` like this and it would work fine:

```
get_output(T, input) = Output("lots of data", T(input))
```

By the way, I would *strongly recommend against doing this*, but it is possible to cheat, since the Julia compiler does not enforce that constructors actually return instances of the types that they are supposed to construct:

```
struct Output{T <: Number}
    other_details::String
    numeric_output::T
end

struct get_output{T} end

function get_output{T}(input) where {T <: Number}
    Output("lots of data", T(input))
end
```

```
julia> get_output{Float64}(1)
Output{Float64}("lots of data", 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks - this works great. Interesting to work with a language where types are first-class citizens - this seems like a very cool feature.